# Custom Page Template - Widgets of wrong sidebar

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets

I have created a blog page and added some widgets to it. So far so good...

Than I created a custom page by putting a file with

```
/**
 * Template Name: Shop
**/

<?php
/**
 * Template Name: TWArms Shop (Shop)
**/


wp_enqueue_style( 'twarms', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/twarms.css' );

get_header();

echo do_shortcode("[rev_slider alias='shop-header11']");

?>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="largegap"></div>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-9 shop-main">

 <?php
 if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ?>
 <div class="shop-post">

 <div class="text-center">
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
 </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
 <?php
 endwhile;
 }
 ?>

 <nav>
 <ul class="pager">
 <li><?php next_posts_link('Previous'); ?></li>
 <li><?php previous_posts_link('Next'); ?></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>

</div><!-- /.shop-main -->

<div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="largegap"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="largegap"></div>
</div>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

into my template folder. If I create a new page in the admin section, using this template, all widgets, which where associated to the the blog page are also shown on the new page.

If I add, remove or change the widgets, the changes are also visible on the blog page.

what can I do to get Wordpress to distinguish both sides?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was, that the new shop page, which I created for WooCommerce, was not defined as the shop page int the WooCommerce settings.